# unable to read the EOF character in C

Tags: c, string, input, eof

I have a problem with reading the EOF character for the last input in C

```
j=0;       
while(*(name2+j)!='\n'){
    if(*(name2+j) == ' '){
        j++;
        continue;
    }
    d[tolower(*(name2+j))]++;
    j++;
}
```

For the last input, there is no new line character, the value of j is getting set to very large number for a very small string. So, to consider the end of file, i modified the while condition to

```
while(*(name2+j)!='\n' && (*(name2+j))!=EOF)
```

but still i am having the same problem. Can someone tell if i am missing something here ? Thanks.

Comment: What is the declaration of `name2`? Keep in mind that `EOF` *cannot* fit in a `char` variable.

Comment: EOF is usually a sign of wrong programming.

Comment: yeah.. name2 was char array, understood what the problem is. thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EOF` is an integer value outside the range of a `char` (since its very purpose is to indicate that *no* `char` is present), so if you want to be able to compare a value to `EOF`, then you need to retrieve and store that value as an `int` rather than as a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

How did you declare `name2` and set it? `char` can't contain an `EOF`, but if you got it by the standard input functions, you should have a `'\0'` terminates it. if so, just change the condition to

```
while (name2[j] && name2[j]!='\n')
```